# Register twinkle with asterisk:

Tags: voip, asterisk, voice

I am trying to register twinkle with asterisk. But not able to register it. I tried everything but no success. When I try to register it shows fetching **registrations failed: 503 Service Unavailable**

Here is the log:

```
+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.360376 INFO SIP ::send_sip_udp
Send to: udp:111.118.250.238:5060
REGISTER sip:111.118.250.238 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.53:5059;rport;branch=z9hG4bKvqfojppg
Max-Forwards: 70
To: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>
From: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>;tag=yseuu
Call-ID: cfslniyxacntoop@localhost.localdomain
CSeq: 858 REGISTER
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,INFO,MESSAGE
User-Agent: Twinkle/1.4.2
Content-Length: 0


---

+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.362151 INFO NORMAL ::listen_udp
Received ICMP from: 111.118.250.238
ICMP type: 3
ICMP code: 10
Destination of packet causing ICMP: 111.118.250.238:5060
Socket error: 113 No route to host
---

+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.362239 INFO NORMAL t_tc_non_invite::process_icmp
ICMP error received.
---
+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.362312 INFO NORMAL t_tc_non_invite::process_failure
Transaction failed.

Send internal:
SIP/2.0 503 Service Unavailable
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.53:5059;rport;branch=z9hG4bKvqfojppg
To: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>;tag=frsdw
From: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>;tag=yseuu
Call-ID: cfslniyxacntoop@localhost.localdomain
CSeq: 858 REGISTER
Server: Twinkle/1.4.2
Content-Length: 0

---

+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.362415 INFO NORMAL t_phone_user::handle_response_out_of_dialog
Failover to next destination.
---

+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.362650 INFO SIP ::send_sip_udp
Send to: udp:111.118.250.238:5060
REGISTER sip:111.118.250.238 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.53:5059;rport;branch=z9hG4bKfqgzykug
Max-Forwards: 70
To: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>
From: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>;tag=yseuu
Call-ID: cfslniyxacntoop@localhost.localdomain
CSeq: 859 REGISTER
Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,OPTIONS,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,INFO,MESSAGE
User-Agent: Twinkle/1.4.2
Content-Length: 0


---

+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.364172 INFO NORMAL ::listen_udp
Received ICMP from: 111.118.250.238
ICMP type: 3
ICMP code: 10
Destination of packet causing ICMP: 111.118.250.238:5060
Socket error: 113 No route to host
---

+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.364256 INFO NORMAL t_tc_non_invite::process_icmp
ICMP error received.
---

+++ 6-3-2013 17:09:03.364325 INFO NORMAL t_tc_non_invite::process_failure
Transaction failed.

Send internal:
SIP/2.0 503 Service Unavailable
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.53:5059;rport;branch=z9hG4bKfqgzykug
To: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>;tag=kvpyf
From: "fake4" <sip:fake4@111.118.250.238>;tag=yseuu
Call-ID: cfslniyxacntoop@localhost.localdomain
CSeq: 859 REGISTER
Server: Twinkle/1.4.2
Content-Length: 0
```

I think it is the problem of firewall. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debug on asterisk side use following(from ssh/console)

```
asterisk -rvvvv
sip set debug on
```

hope it will give you enought info about problem. If you see nothing on asterisk - you need open port 5060 udp on all firewalls in path.

Comment: port 5060 udp was not open. Thanks for your response